# Java based key-value store (embedded database) with incremental persistence and transactions

Tags: java, database, embedded-database

Any recommendations for a Java based key-value store embedded database? Requirements are:

1. It should support transactions
2. It should support saving and loading from incremental changes. What I mean by this is that let's say I create an instance of the db, add 1 billion records, then save. After that I add one more record and save. Needless to say I don't want it to write all the records all over again.

What I am planning to use it for?

I will be mostly storing text. I don't need SQL API. I just want a `HashMap<String, String>` or `HashMap<Integer, String>` (Id->Text) with increment persistence and transaction support.

Comment: What "embedded" means for you?

Comment: Eclipse Store https://eclipsestore.io/ will do the job.